# display static ASCII data (like curses) in Windows CLion?

Tags: c, debugging, display, clion

I am using CLion in Windows. It has a stdout-like terminal that allows printf output to be shown. In some cases, however, I would like to have a static display that is updated. For example, I might have a matrix, and I want to see the values in the matrix update as the program runs. I do not want to print the matrix out to stdout because it would just scroll off the screen and be unreadable. I need the matrix to stay in one place and just update. In Unix I can do things like this with [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)). Obviously I could start writing Windows graphical applications, but that would be complicated and time consuming. Is there any easy way to get an ASCII 2D display of information using CLion for Windows?

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a graphical debugger where you can tell it to watch a variable.

Comment: I use PhpStorm, and I've always found JetBrains tech support to be very helpful. If there's a way to do what you want, they should be able to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

In CLion you may set breakpoints at appropriate positions (at the points where you'd like to see the values of the variables) and run the program in 'Debug' mode.

All the variables and their values at that point could be accessed in the variables tab and you may add them to your 'watch list' so that they can stand out from rest of the variables.

CLion has a pretty great debugger. You can even evaluate some statements using those variables.

For example :

[image]